# how do i access student model from usercontroller

Tags: laravel

I am trying to retrieve all students from the `UserController` but when I dump students all array I get empty collection in my view. Is the middleware preventing access to the model and how do I resolve it.

This is my UserController

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Student;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\BaseController;

class UserController extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth')->except('index');
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        $students = Student::all();
        dd($students);
    }
}
```

This is my Student model

```php
use App\Models\Course;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Student extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'students';

    protected $fillable = [
        'firstname', 'middlename', 'lastname', 'index_no', 'parent_id',
        'regular_or_weekend',
        'course_id',
        'nationality',
        'image'
    ];
}
```

this is my User model

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $fillable = [
        'index_no', 'password',
    ];
}
```

I want to compare student's `index_no` with the corresponding user's `index_no`, if they matched then I gets the students detail.

Comment: It's not the middleware, it wouldn't let you reach the `dd($students)` at all, it appears that you just don't have any records in the `students` table

Comment: @Saly3301 i do have records in students table

Comment: Try `\DB::table('students')->get();`

Comment: Also! why are you extending `BaseController` instead of `Controller`? you can neither authorize or validate requests nor dispatch jobs this way

Comment: @Saly3301 how do i find a student using the user's id

Comment: the BaseController contains  other functionalities which i will use later

Comment: And so does `Controller` by logic of inheritance

Comment: i extended the Controller in the BaseController

Comment: You can get student by user id like so `\DB::table('students')->find($user->id);`

Comment: @sally3301 thank for your help and i appreciate your time spent

Comment: is your problem completely solved now?

Comment: @sally3301 yes, thanks once again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can proceed here.

- Eloquent
- DB query

**Using Eloquent**

```
$students = App\ Student::find($user->id);
```

**Using DB query**

```
$students = \DB::table('students')->find($user->id);
```